# Cauchy's formula for repeated integrals proof by induction

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I was trying to follow along with the proof on Wikipedia for Cauchy's formula for repeated integrals and I'm stuck on the last step. How do you go from
$$\int_a^x \frac {d}{dy} \left( \int_a^y (y-t)^nf(t)dt\right) dy$$
to
$$\int_a^x (x-t)^nf(t) dt$$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We always have$$\int_a^b\frac{\mathrm d\varphi}{\mathrm dy}\,\mathrm dy=\varphi(b)-\varphi(a),$$by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. So,$$\int_a^x\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dy}\left(\int_a^y(y-t)^nf(t)\,\mathrm dt\right)\,\mathrm dy=\int_a^x(x-t)^nf(t)\,\mathrm dt-\overbrace{\int_a^a(a-t)^nf(t)\,\mathrm dt}^{\phantom{0}=0}.$$

Comment: Oh ok, I see now. The phi in this case is the inner integral.Thank you!

Comment: Carlos.Last line: Shouldn't the $x$ in the integrand be $a$ ?

Comment: @PeterSzilas Sure. I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I´m going to show a sketch of a proof for Cauchy´s formula for repeated integrals.
The formula says:
$$f^{(-n)}(x)=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\int_{a}^{x} (x-t)^{n-1}f(t)dt$$ 
Let start with $n=3$, and later on we try to generalize it.
Then:
$$f^{(-3)}(x)=\int_{a}^{x} \int_{a}^{u} \int_{a}^{s}f(t)dtdsdu $$
$$\int_{a}^{x} \int_{a}^{u} \int_{a}^{s}f(t)dtdsdu=\int_{a}^{x}\left[ \int_{a}^{u} \int_{a}^{s}f(t)dtds\right]du $$
Now concentrate in the double integral inside the parenthesis. Here is a sketch of it´s region of integration.[image]

We can swap the order the integration, according to the following picture:

[image]

If we do so, we get the following expression for the inner double integral
$$ \int_{a}^{u} \int_{a}^{s}f(t)dtds=\int_{a}^{u} \int_{t}^{u} f(t)dsdt$$
$$\int_{a}^{u} \int_{t}^{u} f(t)dsdt=\int_{a}^{u}f(t)dt \int_{t}^{u}ds=\int_{a}^{u}(u-t)f(t)dt$$

$$ \Rightarrow f^{(-3)}(x)=\int_{a}^{x} \int_{a}^{u} \int_{a}^{s}f(t)dtdsdu =\int_{a}^{x} \left[\int_{a}^{u}(u-t)f(t)dt\right]du$$

Proceeding in the same way we did before (changing the order of integration), we get
$$\int_{a}^{x} \int_{a}^{u}(u-t)f(t)dtdu=\int_{a}^{x} \int_{t}^{x}(u-t)f(t)dudt$$
$$\int_{a}^{x} \int_{t}^{x}(u-t)f(t)dudt=\int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt \int_{t}^{x}(u-t)du$$
The second integral on the right hand side of the equation can be solved using a substitution: let $s=u-t \Rightarrow ds=du$
$$\int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt \int_{t}^{x}(u-t)du=\int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt\int_{0}^{x-t} sds$$
And finally we get:
$$f^{(-3)}(x)=\int_{a}^{x} \int_{a}^{u} \int_{a}^{s}f(t)dtdsdu =\int_{a}^{x} \frac{(x-t)^{2}}{2!}f(t)dt$$
It´s starting to emerge a pattern, if we keep integrating further, we may prove by induction Cauchy´s formula.

Comment: Hi, I really I appreciate the sketch of the region of integration! Can you explain why we think of $u$ as a constant and not a variable in your sketch? I thought $u$ would be a variable coming from $f(u) = \int_{a}^{u}f(t)dt$

Comment: u is the upper limit of the integral, it´s a fixed constant.