# Reducing multiple integrals to single integral

Tags: calculus, integration

In our integral equations course, we derived the following equation
$$
\int_0^x\int_0^{x_1} ...\int_0^{x_{n-1}}u(x_n)dx_ndx_{n-1}...dx_1=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\int_0^x(x-t)^{n-1}u(t)dt
$$

Then my professor said that it is easy to see from this, that

$$
\int_0^x\int_0^{x_1} ...\int_0^{x_{n-1}}(x-x_n)u(x_n)dx_ndx_{n-1}...dx_1=\frac{1}{n!}\int_0^x(x-t)^{n}u(t)dt
$$
This same result is given in our [textbox](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783642214493)

However, when I  checked the last equation with some simple example ($u(t)=1,n=2$) it seems that the factor $\frac{1}{n!}$ should be $\frac{1}{(n-1)!}$. Is this correct?

$$
\frac{1}{2!}\int_0^x (x-t)^2 \, dt=\frac{x^3}{6}
$$
$$
\int _0^x\int _0^{x_1}(x-x_2)dx_2dx_1=\frac{x^3}{3}
$$

$\frac{1}{2!}$ should be $\frac{1}{1!}$.

Comment: make a change of variable on the L.H.S. of the last equation $x-t=w$ and proceed the same way you did to proof the first equation, which I assume that it was by changing the order of integration. Then see if you can get the result.

Comment: @Ricardo770, I dont see how this changes anything?

Comment: see this answer I gave in another post :  https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3486676/238708   .

Comment: @Ricardo770, but your proof only proves the first equation. My question is about the second equation.

Comment: the second equation is one more interation of the same process.

Comment: What about the example I provided. Is it wrong?

Comment: @Isaac The formula in the textbook isn't what you have in the question. Look at the upper bounds for the integrals in (1.130)

Comment: @podiki, I have asked my professor before about (1.130) and he said it just means $\int_0^x\int_0^{x_1} ...\int_0^{x_{n-1}}(x-x_n)u(x_n)dx_ndx_{n-1}...dx_1$! which started my confusion

Answer (score 1):

You have

$$\int_0^x\int_0^{x_1} ...\int_0^{x_{n-1}}f(x_n)dx_ndx_{n-1}...dx_1=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\int_0^x(x-t)^{n-1}f(t)dt \tag{1}$$

Integrate both sides from $0$ to $u$

$$\int_0^u\int_0^x\int_0^{x_1} ...\int_0^{x_{n-1}}f(x_n)dx_ndx_{n-1}...dx_1\,dx=\frac{1}{(n-1)!} \int_0^u\int_0^x(x-t)^{n-1}f(t)\, dt \, dx \tag{2}$$

Now, focus on the R.H.S. of $(2)$

$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{(n-1)!} \int_0^u\int_0^x(x-t)^{n-1}f(t)\, dt \, dx &=\frac{1}{(n-1)!} \int_0^u\int_t^u(x-t)^{n-1}f(t)\, dx \, dt\\
 &=\frac{1}{(n-1)!} \int_0^u f(t)\int_t^u(x-t)^{n-1}\, dx \, dt\\
&=\frac{1}{(n-1)!} \int_0^u f(t)\int_0^{u-t} w^{n-1}\, dw \, dt\\
&=\frac{1}{(n-1)!} \int_0^u f(t)\left(\frac{w^n}{n}\Big|_0^{u-t} \right) \, dt\\
&=\frac{1}{n!} \int_0^u (u-t)^n f(t) \, dt\\
&=\frac{1}{n!} \int_0^x (x-t)^n f(t) \, dt \qquad \blacksquare\\
\end{aligned}$$

Then $(2)$ becomes

$$\int_0^x\int_0^{x_1}\int_0^{x_2} ...\int_0^{x_{n}}f(x_{n+1})dx_{n+1}dx_{n}...dx_1\,dx=\frac{1}{n!} \int_0^x (x-t)^n f(t) \, dt \tag{3}$$

Note that the L.H.S. of $(1)$ has $n$ integrals and that the the L.H.S. of $(2)$ has $n+1$ integrals

Comment: I still don't see where $\int_0^x\int_0^{x_1} ...\int_0^{x_{n-1}}(x-x_n)f(x_n)dx_ndx_{n-1}...dx_1$ is in your answer.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5SGX.png also in the textbox it says there are $n$ integrals

Comment: How would you reduce $\int_0^x\int_0^{x_1} ...\int_0^{x_{n-1}}(x-x_n)f(x_n)dx_ndx_{n-1}...dx_1$ to a single integral?

Comment: bring the outmost integral of the L.H.S. of  $(3)$ in my answer  inside

Comment: What is $u$ in the final equation?

Comment: just a dummy variable, you could switch the indices to start in $n-1$ to $n$ and then $x$ if you wish

Comment: @Ricardo770, are you saying that $
\int_0^x\int_0^{x_1} ...\int_0^{x_{n-1}}(x-x_n)f(x_n)dx_ndx_{n-1}...dx_1=\frac{1}{n!}\int_0^x(x-t)^{n}f(t)dt
$? but this clearly doesn't work for $f=1,n=2$

Comment: Now the LHS of the final answer has $n+2$ differentials but only $n$ integrals

Comment: there was a typo, fixed it.

Comment: @Ricardo770, I am not sure you have answered the question.

Comment: @Isaac Integration by parts may work to prove what you are looking for, I´ll try to use it

Comment: @gbd Indeed, I haven´t, I will try a different approach via integration by parts

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as stated in your question the second formula should have a factor of $\frac{1}{(n-1)!}$. To see this we will rewrite the first equation as

$$\int_0^x \int_0^{x_1}\cdots\int_0^{x_{n-1}}f(x_n)dx_n dx_{n-1}\cdots dx_1=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\int_0^x(x-t)^{n-1}f(t)dt$$

and let $f(t)=(x-t)u(t)$ then we obtain

$$\int_0^x \int_0^{x_1}\cdots\int_0^{x_{n-1}}(x-x_n)u(x_n)dx_n dx_{n-1}\cdots dx_1=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\int_0^x(x-t)^{n}u(t)dt.$$

However, as I wrote in a comment, this isn't really equation (1.130) from your textbook.